# Paypal Switching from Sandbox to Live - Swift SDK

Tags: swift, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I successfully integrated Paypal in my Application using Paypal SDK in Swift.
In order to test i kept the environment on sandbox but now when i am trying to switch to live using live Client ID Still i am getting the mockup Data.

PayPalMobile .initializeWithClientIds(forEnvironments: [PayPalEnvironmentProduction: "my client ID for production"
            ])

Need Help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In addition to setting the clientID for each environment, you also need to set which environment you are using.

For example in the sample app: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/SampleApp/PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App/ZZMainViewController.m#L12